# Forwarding -- ok for SEO, or should I reinstall WordPress at the forwarded domain?

Tags: seo, domain-forwarding

If my main market is UK, and I have both:

mydomain.co.uk

and:

mydomain.com

and I want to market the site using the .co.uk domain

and I only have one set of content -- one website, that I want to be seen by visitors to either domain..

and I have a WordPress site at mydomain.com, with url forwarding (with masking I think it is) so people can go to the .co.uk domain and see the content of the dotcom domain, is that ok from an SEO point of view (or from any other point of view)?

Or is it better to reinstall WordPress so it's at the .co.uk domain, with forwarding of the .com domain?

Comment: What URL are you using to market the site? .co.uk or .com? and just to confirm that you want the same content on both URLs?

Comment: using .co.uk to market the site. And yes, the same content at both urls

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would have the content hosted on .co.uk and a redirect from .com to the content on .co.uk, that way any links will gain SEO momentum for the .co.uk domain.

Answer (score 1):

If the content on both .com and .co.uk sites is the same, you really should redirect from one domain to another, or at very least using rel=canonical for each page pointing only at one TLD. Otherwise Google might see it as content duplication.

Answer (score 0):

From an SEO perspective, its better if you have as many domain names as possible listed in Google/Bing. However, there is a chance that you could get penalized for having multiple domain names to increase your SERP. If your website is selling multiple products then you can increase your SEO if you have a domain name for each product (ie: lets say your "Microsoft", then you can improve your SEO with windows8.com, office.com, hotmail.com). If you want to take a chance (and hopefully not get penalized) then you can have both domain names listed so they are different URLs but show the same content. As for choosing which domain name is better, if your website is targeting people in the UK then I would go with ".co.uk" and if your website is global then I would go with ".com".